# Irreducible $G$-group, Irreducible $G$-module.

Tags: group-theory, modules

Let $G$ and $M$ be two groups. Let $M$ be a $G$-group. What does an irreducible $G$-group mean? I have heard the term irreducibility for modules. So, what actually irreducibility means here? Is that something related to $G$-module? However, when we say $M$ is a $G$-module, in that case, $M$ has to be an abelian group. Here, $M$ is an arbitrary group. It does not make sense to me. Please help me with this.
For the definition of $G$-groups, you can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_with_operators.
For the definition of $G$-modules, you can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-module.

Comment: The most likely meaning is that there $M$ has no proper nontrivial $G$-invariant subgroups.

Comment: It makes sense. In particular, if M is an abelian group, then can we say that M is a G-module? In that case, Irreducibility of G-module coincide with the irreducibility of G-group?

Comment: Or maybe no proper nontrivial $G$-invariant *normal* subgroups? Where did you come across the term "irreducible $G$-group"? It may not have a universally agreed meaning.

Comment: I came across this term in this paper <https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869303002758>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paper

*Lafuente, Julio P.; Lizasoain, I.; Ochoa, Gustavo*, [**Projective G-groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(00)00181-X), J. Pure Appl. Algebra 165, No. 2, 213-225 (2001). [ZBL1017.20019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1017.20019),

an irreducible $G$-group is defined to be a group with an action of $G$ by group automorphisms that has no proper nontrivial $G$-invariant **normal** subgroups.

That doesn't prove that this is the same as the  definition intended in the paper

*Detomi, E.; Lucchini, A.*, [**Crowns and factorization of the probabilistic zeta function of a finite group.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0021-8693(03)00275-8), J. Algebra 265, No. 2, 651-668 (2003). [ZBL1072.20031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1072.20031),

where the OP said (in comments) that he encountered the term, but that paper refers to another paper co-authored by Lafuente for other terminology regarding $G$-groups, so it seems very likely that this is the intended definition.

Comment: Yeah. They might be different. In the second paper, they are taking chief factors of G as irreducible G-groups.  In that case, the above definition works. In general, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen 'an irreducible $G$-group' for an arbitrary group $M$. However, there is at least a notion of *a simple $G$-group* for a (group) representation $\pi \colon G \to \operatorname{Aut}M$; see [Aschbacher 2000, pp. [22](https://books.google.com/books?id=BprbtnlI6HEC&pg=PA22)f.], for instance. I think this is what it means as D. Holt already commented. (Added. I mean, a group $M$ without non-trivial proper $G$-invariant *normal* subgroup as J. Rickard noted.)

If $M$ is abelian, then one can extend the action of $G$ on $M$ and regard $M$ as a $\mathbb ZG$-module (and vice versa). So you can (comfortably?) talk about simplicity/irreducibility. Or you may want to see everything from the viewpoint of abstract representations discussed in pp. 9f. in the above book.